# Restricting CloudFront CORS to custom domain

Tags: amazon-s3, cors, amazon-cloudfront, cdn, cross-origin-resource-policy

I am trying to restrict the access to my CloudFront distribution to my custom domain as in, it will only serve to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), if  a request comes from [www.leech-domain.com](http://www.leech-domain.com) it should return a 403 or whatever. The cloudfront servers resources from an s3 bucket.

I've configured cloudfront like this:
[CloudFront config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gm8tM.png)
In which the Response Headers policy is:
[Response Headers Policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHntw.png)
The s3 bucket has the following CORS:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "https://www.example.com",
            "https://subdomain.example.com"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Comment: What if I rephrase it like this: Is it possible to configure CloudFront so that my assets can only be embeded on a set of given domains?

Comment: Probably (I'm not that familiar with CloudFront), but not certainly with CORS anyway.

Comment: Hold on! If you want to prevent assets from being loaded cross-origin, look into Cross-Origin Resource Policy (CORP), which is distinct from CORS.